# Problems installing apache2 on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-http-server, mod-wsgi

I have apache installed manually from the source code, but I require now to install it using apt-get, because it seems this will make stuff easier to install mod_wsgi from apt-get also (it will see that apache2 is installed, I guess)

so now when I run `sudo apt-get install apache2` I got the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  apache2: Depends: apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.10) but it is not going to be installed or
                    apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.10) but it is not going to be installed or
                    apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.10) but it is not going to be installed or
                    apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.10) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

and even when trying to install apache2.2.-bin (as 2.2-common depends on it), the following error is raised:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  apache2.2-bin: Depends: libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 but it is not going to be installed or
                          libaprutil1-dbd-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                          libaprutil1-dbd-odbc but it is not going to be installed or
                          libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql but it is not going to be installed or
                          libaprutil1-dbd-freetds but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libaprutil1-ldap but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Skimming around I understood that it says that it doesn't know which one of the dependencies to install (seems all work).

and this last error when running for example: `sudo apt-get install libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3: Depends: libaprutil1 (= 1.3.9+dfsg-3ubuntu0.10.04.1) but 1.3.9+dfsg-5 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

You don't install just 'apache2' as that is the generic component. You need to install a specific MPM, such as 'apache2-mpm-worker'. Did you try that?

Comment: yes, and it doesn't work also as it depends on apache2.2-bin, and it has the error shown above :(

Comment: This should not be that hard. Looks like something has been screwed up in your system.